# How to scroll to a given row when WPF DataGrid is loaded

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I display a few thousand rows in a WPF `DataGrid`, but would like to automatically scroll to a specific row when it is loaded (and later also add a button to scroll to this specific row). Is it possible to achieve it via data binding or from a view model property?

Of course, I've already browsed the Internet, but could not find any corresponding property.. For exemple, `SelectedCells` only has a `get` accessor (but I don't think it would have scrolled whatsoever anyway). I don't think that the other properties, such as `SelectedItem` helps.

Thanks for any insights :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options: scroll to a row without selecting it and scroll to a row and select it.

### Scroll to row without selecting it

This solution works for any `DataGrid.SelectionUnit` value (cell or row based selection).

You set the row from a property in your view model, which binds to `DataGrid.CurrentItem`.

Scrolling must be handled by the `DataGrid` by handling the `DataGrid.CurrentCellChanged` event.

**View model (must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)**

```
object currentRow = this.DataSource[currentRowIndex];
this.CurrentRow = currentRow;
```

**View.xaml**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"  
          CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentRow}"
          CurrentCellChanged="DataGrid_OnCurrentCellChanged" />
```

**View.xaml.cs**

```
private void DataGrid_OnCurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
  dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.CurrentItem);
}
```

---

### Scroll to row by selecting it

This solution works only for `DataGrid.SelectionUnit` values `DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow` or `DataGridSelectionUnit.CellOrRowHeader` (not cell-only based selection - cell-only solution must completely handle selection and scroll in view).

You set the selected row from a property in your view model, which binds to `DataGrid.SelectedItem`.

Scrolling must be handled by the `DataGrid` by handling the `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event.

**View model (must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)**

```
object selectedRow = this.DataSource[currentRowIndex];
this.SelectedRow = selectedRow;
```

**View.xaml**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"  
          SelecetedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
          SelectionChanged="DataGrid_OnCurrentCellChanged" />
```

**View.xaml.cs**

```
private void DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
  dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer. It works perfectly well :-) For the time being, I don't want to selected the scrolled row, but it is always something to keep in mind.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a MVVM format?

Comment: This is 100% MVVM compliant. Scrolling is UI logic. It belongs to the view domain (in case you expect it to be in the view model). As the you can see in the example, the implicit row selection based on the data model is handled in the view model.

Comment: Back a few years later (I didn't realize first that I raised this question myself when searching on stackoverflow). Is it possible to ensure that the `ScrollIntoView` always shows the scrolled item at the top of the `DataGrid`?